# SQLite Query Issues

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi I am new to Android SQlite and following couple of examples to learn. I am trying to create a query that will fetch the number of IDs available in the database and its returning me errors as something is wrong with my query so I need some help to fix this query:

```
public Cursor getIds()
{
     return database.query(false, "details", "_id", "Select", "COUNT", null, null, null, null, null)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should provide some more details because we cannot answer your question. What is the DB structure for example?

Comment: and what errors do you get?

Comment: can you post logcat of that errors?

Comment: its a simple database. Table name is details, and it has _id(auto Increment), username, password fields in it. And I want to check on app load that my DB isn't empty so that's why I am building this query to get the Count of _id. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this method allows use of Aggregate function. You will have to use the rawQuery() method. Also, 4th and 5th parameter should be `selection` and `selectionArgs`. `public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`

Comment: Cursor don't work like this.
Here is the link that might help you: [Android-SQLITE-DATABASE-TUTORIAL](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Cursor getIds()
{
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(_Id) AS CountTotal FROM details";
    return db.rawQuery(sql, null); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the query is wrong

> query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[]
>   selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)

you should have somethin like that:

```
Cursor c=query("TABLE NAME",new String[]{"COLUMN_ID_NAME"},null,null,null,null);
return c.getCount();
```

Comment: But how can i check the "Count" using this query? Thanks.